# Error: The model backing the 'NameDbContext' context has changed since the database was created

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-web-api2

The original issue I was trying to solve was related to this error message. This is happening in a Web API 2 Project running on Azure.

**Error 1**

*Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Merchant_MerchantId' on table 'Keys' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION,or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.*

The FOREGIN KEY error message was only introduced after I tried to upload a release build of my API to my Azure App Service. I recently upgrade to version 15.9.11 of Visual Studio 2017, but I have no idea if that is the cause of the FOREIGN KEY issue that started this mess. This API and database has been running for years with no problems whatsoever.

To try and fix the problem, I added the following line to my OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) method.

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Adding the line kind of fixed the issue and Error 1 has gone away, but now the API is not finding records that are actually in the database. I'm not sure why that is.

I have since commented out the line and uploaded a new build of my App Service. I'm now getting this error message.

**Error 2**

*Error: The model backing the 'NameDbContext' context has changed since the database was created.*

At this stage, I'm causing more problems instead of fixing my original problem.

Any help to recover from this mess is much appreciated! Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

I worked with a Microsoft Engineer on the "The model backing the 'NameDbContext' context has changed since the database was created" error. I added the following to the Application_Start() in the Global.asax.cs file. Adding this did not delete or alter any of my data in SQL. Error message 2 has gone away. The API is still not returning records that are in the database, so I still have a problem to fix.

```
Database.SetInitializer<FaceOffersDbContext>(null);
```

**UPDATE 2**

I ran my API locally with no problems. This means that the problem is only happening in Azure. I'm working with Microsoft to narrow down the issue and come up with a fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your database schema is changed and not at per with your entity framework, You may try to forcefully update your database using package manager console.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Can you be a little more specific? Is there a way to undo what modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>(); seems to have done? I would like to try and go back to life before I added this line of code. :) I can then get back to working on the original error.

Comment: Perhaps I could Add the OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention back like so. modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();